# Load php after submit button is pressed

Tags: php, html

Right now, I have 2 seperate pages to upload an image onto the server. My goal is to get all this to work on one page.

MySite.com/index.html

```
 <html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Then there is MySite.com/upload_file.php

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

How can I make this php code load on /index.html when the submit button is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check for `isset()` of submit button, so add at the top

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
     $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
     //all your code....
}
```

Additionally you can use a single page with an `else` condition by placing there your form

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your page to listen for the id "file" (from your input box) being sent. You may wish to namespace it though, to avoid potential conflicts.

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST['file'] ) ) {
    //put your code here

    return;
} 
?>

<!-- your html here -->
```